# How would you say "body" as in when stating a law of physics?

Tags: word-request, terminology, science

When writing [a Reddit post in Latin](https://www.reddit.com/r/latin/comments/17yt18h/quid_censetis_de_prohibitione_sclopetorum), I used the word "*corpus*" in the singular when stating the second law of thermodynamics:

> Secunda lex thermodynamicae docet nobis quia nullum **corpus** potest agere laborem (productum fortiae et distantiae, quod metimur in joulibus) ex sua ipsius energia internale. Per secundam legem thermodynamicae, **corpus**, ut possit laborem facere, debet energiam accipere ab alio altero **corpore**.

Is that correct?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, *corpus* is correct for "body" in the sense used in physics.
That is the word Newton used in his [laws of motion](https://la.wikisource.org/wiki/Philosophiae_Naturalis_Principia_Mathematica/Axiomata,_sive_Leges_Motus):

> 1. **Corpus** omne perseverare in statu suo quiescendi vel movendi uniformiter in directum, nisi quatenus a viribus impressis cogitur statum illum mutare.
> 2. Mutationem motus proportionalem esse vi motrici impressæ, & ﬁeri secundum lineam rectam qua vis illa imprimitur.
> 3. Actioni contrariam semper & æqualem esse reactionem: sive **corporum** duorum actiones in se mutuo semper esse æquales & in partes contrarias dirigi.

Comment: And using "fortia" for "force" is... incorrect, or?

Comment: @FlatAssembler As you can see, Newton uses *vis*. I haven't come across *fortia* for "force" and it does strike me as odd.

Comment: I would venture that _corpus_ be also correct when talking about **fields and skew fileds** in abstract algebra.

Comment: @NicolasMiari I wouldn't use *corpus* for that, but figuring out the correct translation should be taken to a separate question.

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta The concept itself is from the 19th century if I'm not mistaken, so defintiely not the same era as Newton... But the original is German _Körper_, and all romance languages seem to use a descendant of _corpus_ as well (English seems to be the outlier)... Acknowledging the derailing the discussion, and out of curiosity: What would you use instead?

Comment: @NicolasMiari I'm not going to derail this conversation. It should be taken either to a new question or to [the site's chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36130/conloqvivm).